# Box2DJS on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, box2d

I have already implemented Box2dWeb engine into a server, but now I realised that the Box2DJS is probably a better choice. But since I'm new at JavaScript I don't know how to "import" the Box2DJS engine (it has lots of .js files). Is it that obvious and I just don't realise it? Since I've been searching for a while now and couldn't find how to do that with Node.js. Sorry for the noob question. How do I use the [Box2DJS](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/)  engine with Node.js? I guess it's not "require()"? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I have used Box2dweb and found it really good. You can reference the API from the original Flash version here: www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was declaring the fixtures wrong (it wasn't throwing any errors). I thought that the engine was kinda broken because the bodies were behaving weird compared to what they were set to do.